# Configure using statements sorting in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, using

I'm working with a Unity project and I'm using Visual Studio, but since I program quite a lot in Python I'm used to the way imports are sorted in PyCharm using PEP8 style.

Is there any way to set up Visual Studio to do something similar?

I've tried the following:

- Looking for an option in the `.editorconfig` file documentation.
- Fiddled around in Visual Studio configuration.
- Checked the MSDN articles that seemed related.

So what currently happens when I sort the using statements is the following:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using MyProject.NamespaceA.NamespaceB;
using MyProject.NamespaceC.NamespaceD;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
```

What I would like to happen is the following instead:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

using MyProject.NamespaceA.NamespaceB;
using MyProject.NamespaceC.NamespaceD;
```

It may sound like a silly change but I would like it to work this way if possible.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with all those other tags -- only c# and visual studio.

Comment: What is the sorting logic here? `MyProject.NamespaceA.NamespaceB` is after `UnityEditor`, which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing available out of the box in Visual Studio or in the popular style analyzers that I know of.

I guess it should be possible to create custom rule and custom code fix for [StyleCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers), something similar to [SA1210](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1210.md) and [SA1208](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1208.md). They both have implemented [code fixes](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/tree/64f2d60af0251d2213dbdac6f3ab202cc4a0362e#current-status) (automatic fix that could be applied per case or for the whole solution).